# QT Android - The GDB process terminated unexpectedly (exit code 0)

Tags: android, qt

All of the sudden, when trying to deploy and debug QT Android app that's what I get. The app gets deployed just fine and runs just fine however GDB dies. Already tried removing entire Android-SDK folder and redownloading. Is it really the time to wipe-out the entire QT installation (again) ?

**Two message boxes are shown:**

**Title:**"Executable Failed"

**Msg:** Command aborted"

**Title:** "Unexpected GDB Exit - QT Creator"

**Msg:** "The GDB process terminated unexpectedly (exit code 0)."

**App log:**

> 10:22:07: Debugging starts W main    : type=1400 audit(0.0:86622):
> avc: granted { read } for pid=18154 name="u:object_r:net_dns_prop:s0"
> dev="tmpfs" ino=1835 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768
> tcontext=u:object_r:net_dns_prop:s0 tclass=file I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke:
> Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni E ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: Unknown bits set in
> runtime_flags: 0x8000 I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: Reinit property:
> dalvik.vm.checkjni= false W re-initialized>: type=1400
> audit(0.0:86623): avc: denied { read } for pid=18154
> name="u:object_r:mmi_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1831
> scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768
> tcontext=u:object_r:mmi_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 E libc    :
> Access denied finding property "runtime.mmitest.isrunning" D
> ActivityThread: Attach thread to application W ActivityThread:
> Application org.qtproject.PROJECT_NAMEoken is waiting for the debugger
> on port 8100... I System.out: Sending WAIT chunk I System.out:
> Debugger has connected I System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
> I System.out: waiting for debugger to settle... Could not load shared
> library symbols for 312 libraries, e.g.
> /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so. Use the "info sharedlibrary"
> command to see the complete listing. Do you need "set
> solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?I System.out: debugger has settled
> (7129) I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: The ClassLoaderContext is a special
> shared library. I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: QarthPatchMonintor::Init 01-10
> 10:22:16.053 18154 18154 I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke:
> QarthPatchMonintor::StartWatch 01-10 10:22:16.053 18154 18154 I
> ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke:
> QarthPatchMonintor::WatchPackage: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/ 01-10
> 10:22:16.054 18154 18154 I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke:
> QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch:
> /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/org.qtproject.PROJECT_NAMEoken 01-10
> 10:22:16.054 18154 18154 I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke:
> QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/all
> 01-10 10:22:16.054 18154 18154 I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: I
> ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: QarthPatchMonintor::Run 01-10 10:22:16.054 18154
> 18154 I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke:
> QarthPatchMonintor::Reading 01-10 10:22:16.055 18154 18207 I
> ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke:
> QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent 01-10 10:22:16.055 18154 18207 I
> ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke:
> QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent before read 01-10 10:22:16.055
> 18154 18207 I ect.PROJECT_NAMEoke: I HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache
> path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted
> key=org.qtproject.PROJECT_NAMEoken#10165#256 I HwApiCacheMangerEx:
> apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted
> key=org.qtproject.PROJECT_NAMEoken#10165#0 I AwareBitmapCacher: init
> processName:org.qtproject.PROJECT_NAMEoken pid=18154 uid=10165 V
> ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate W System  : ClassLoader
> referenced unknown path: E AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines
> file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@cb0695 V HwWidgetFactory: :
> successes to get AllImpl object and return.... I
> OverScrollerOptimization: start init SmartSlideOverScroller and get
> the overscroller config I OverScrollerOptimization: get the
> overscroller config W WindowDecorActionBar: should not do the
> transition or the transition anim is null or it is running or the
> mContainer view is null or mContainer view hasn't been drawn to screen
> D HwGalleryCacheManagerImpl: mIsEffect:false D Qt JAVA : Class
> org.qtproject.qt5.android.multimedia.QtMultimediaUtils does not
> implement setActivity method I QtCore  : Start I Qt      : qt started
> D ActivityThread: add activity client record, r=
> ActivityRecord{7b59680 token=android.os.BinderProxy@fba4a25
> {org.qtproject.PROJECT_NAMEoken/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity}}
> token= android.os.BinderProxy@fba4a25 D HiTouch_PressGestureDetector:
> onAttached, package=org.qtproject.PROJECT_NAMEoken, windowType=1,
> mHiTouchRestricted=false I iGraphics: [0020080c] pn:
> org.qtproject.PROJECT_NAMEoken, p: 18154 I iGraphics: [0030050c] PV 10
> I iGraphics: [0030050c] no element 'igfx' I iGraphics: [0030050c]
> LoadCloudParams lib file success. E Parcel  : Reading a NULL string
> not supported here. D mali_winsys: EGLint
> new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
> EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000 W
> Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported E         :
> APS:IFLoad:importExternalFunctions, search function
> createNewHwApsUtils failed, dlsym err:undefined symbol:
> createNewHwApsUtils D         : APS:importExternalFunctions OK I
> HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode jank list is null W System.err:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "org.qtproject.qt5.android.network.QtNetwork" on path:
> DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]] W System.err:
> at
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
> W System.err:     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) W System.err:
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) D
> libPROJECT_NAMEoken_armeabi-v7a.so: QML Debugger: Waiting for
> connection on port 16963... D libPROJECT_NAMEoken_armeabi-v7a.so:
> About to request permissions D libPROJECT_NAMEoken_armeabi-v7a.so:
> Permissions granted W libPROJECT_NAMEoken_armeabi-v7a.so:
> qrc:/main.qml:176:5: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo
> properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead:
> function onFoo() { ... } W libEGL  : EGLNativeWindowType
> 0xceced1c8 disconnect failed D mali_winsys: EGLint
> new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
> EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000 D
> mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *,
> EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns
> 0x3000 I Camera  : open camera: 0, package name:
> org.qtproject.PROJECT_NAMEoken D HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory:
> HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory in. I HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory:
> add HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory to memory. I HwCameraUtil:
> notifySurfaceFlingerCameraStatus : isFront = false , isOpend = true D
> SensorManager: 0xb24f49c8 addFd fd=107 W Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is
> not supported W libEGL  : EGLNativeWindowType 0xb96c3008 disconnect
> failed D mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *,
> void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean)
> returns 0x3000 D libPROJECT_NAMEoken_armeabi-v7a.so: needed to resize
> D libPROJECT_NAMEoken_armeabi-v7a.so: size:  0 , new size:  6220800 D
> AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=18154

The app runs fine as usually.